# how to include oracle client 64 bit version in my project 32 bit application c#

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit, oracleclient

i'm Develop a project using visual studio 2010 and oracle client from comm objects in VS 2010 4.0 framework and my windows XP 32 bit operating system. but target system is 64bit server it does not support 32 bit oracle client. so i installed 64 bit oracle client in server.

now now my project not runs in server it asking 32 bit oracle client.

how to include oracle 64 bit version in my project?

(or) any other solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable 32 bit application inside your application pool and use 64bit oracle client.

To enable 32bit application in your application pool follow the styeps:

1. Open IIS Manage using run=> inetmgr
2. Goto Advance settings of your applications pool
3. select 'True' against 'Enable 32 bit application' option.

[image]

Comment: I understand that i need to configure in server to allow 32 bit oracle client using you solution. Then i can install oracle 32 bit client in server. is it correct? Thank you i test it and ask you if any problem persist.